# Filter out struct of null values from an array of structs in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a col in a dataframe which is an array of structs. There are some structs with all null values which I would like to filter out. For example with the following dataframe:

```
+—————+————————————————---------------------—+
|advertiser      |brands                     |
+—————+—————————————---------------------————+
Advertiser1      [{"id" : "a", "type" : "b", "name" : "c"}]
Advertiser2      [{"id" : null, "type" : null, "name" : null}]
+—————+————————————---------------------—————+
```

I would like to filter out the struct with the null values to get:

```
+—————+———————————————---------------------——+
|advertiser      |brands                     |
+—————+————————————---------------------—————+
Advertiser1      [{"id" : "a", "type" : "b", "name" : "c"}]
Advertiser2      []
+—————+—————————————---------------------————+
```

I'm thinking it's something along the lines of this if I can come up with a struct of null values:

```
.withColumn(
    "brands",
    when(
        col("brands").equalTo(*emptyStruct?*),
            null
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the to_json function, brands with all null values will returns [{}].

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter the array elements. Since Spark 3.0 there is a method in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` with the signature:

`filter(column: Column, f: Column => Column): Column`

which does this for you:

```
df.select(
  col("advertiser"),
  filter(col("brands"),
         b =>
           b.getField("id").isNotNull
             && b.getField("type").isNotNull
             && b.getField("name").isNotNull) as "brands"
```

Using Spark 1.6+ you can explode the array, filter the structs and then group by `advertiser`:

```
df.select(col("advertiser"), explode(col("brands")) as "b").
  filter(
    col("b.id").isNotNull &&
      col("b.type").isNotNull &&
      col("b.name").isNotNull)
  .groupBy("advertiser").agg(collect_list("b") as "brands")
```

Comment: Hmm that syntax doesn't seem to work for me. I am getting `error: not found: value filter`. Should it be col("brands").filter() maybe?

Comment: It might be the Spark version you are using, as the error implies the function cannot be found. The answer I posted works on Spark 3.+.